# How can I concatenate list and string in this code?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

```
import os
from subprocess import call

computers = ['\\dc830mjpzplp', '\\dc830mjpzpva']

path1 = "C:\users\public\desktop"

print os.getcwd()

os.chdir("c:\shortcut")

print os.getcwd()

for i in computers:
call(["robocopy", "c:\shortcut", path1])
```

I'm trying to add path1, which is the target path in robocopy to the string in computers. I'm sure there are multiple errors here. I'm attempting to simply copy a file to multiple pcs. I know there are others ways of doing this but I'm trying to learn python. Thanks.

Edit from original:
My while loop ins't working when I select 'y'

```
import os
from subprocess import call

computers = []

print "\n***This script will copy files or folders to specified workstations...***" +"\n"


answer = 'y'

while answer == 'y':
    print "Start by adding a computer name: type DC#xxxx" + "\n"
    name = "\\" + raw_input("> ") 
    computers.append(name)
    print "\n***Add Successful***" + "\n"
    print "Here's the list so far: ", computers 

    print "\nDo you need to add more computers?"
    print "Enter 'y' or 'n'"
    answer = raw_input("> ")

    if answer == 'n':
        print "ok" + "\n"
        break

    else:
        print "I don't understand, please check for typos"
        exit(0)



print "Where is the source directory?"
print "Path can be local or network" + "\n"
source = raw_input("> ")

print "Where is the destination path?"

destination = raw_input("> ")

print "Changing source directory from: " , os.getcwd()

print "Changing source directory to: " , source
os.chdir(source)

print os.getcwd()

for n in computers:
    path = n + destination
call(["robocopy", source, path])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for c in computers:
  path = c + path1
  # now you can use path
```

Also, I suppose that `path1` should not start with `C:\`. `path1` should start with the name of a Windows share present on all the computers apparently.

Edit: you must *escape* backslashes in your strings. `\` has [a special meaning in Python strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), you must write `\\` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. I am trying to copy to C:\ of another workstation, specifically the desktop folder.

Comment: Then you must ensure that C:\ is shared on the target computer, and that you have write permissions. You will have to use a destination path of the form \\TargetComputer\ShareNameForC\...

Comment: Right. I need to add C$, I do have the rights also. Robocopy runs, but the destination outputs like this C:\dc830mjpzplp\users\public\desktop

Comment: I didn't think about adding [i] directly to the variable name. It's the simple things that I tend to overlook, not sure why that is. I learned a lot by posting this question and greatly appreciate your assistance. This is a great community and I hope to return the love in the future. I tested the code and it does exactly what I need it to. This is the foundation, I'm going to make it better. I know there are better ways of accomplishing my intention, but it takes weeks to get things done around here :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems here.

This might be closer to what you are trying to do:

```
import os
from subprocess import call

computers = ['\\\\dc830mjpzplp', '\\\\dc830mjpzpva']

path1 = "\\c$\\users\\public\\desktop" # This might work if you are admin on the remote machine.
# path1 = "\\public" # Or maybe this?

for i in computers:
    call(["robocopy", "c:\\shortcut", i + path1])
```

There are a couple things I don't see here that I should.  First, what is the name of the file that you are trying to copy?  Second, what is the remote UNC path that you can copy to?  You can't add c:\shortcut to a UNC path.

Comment: I am an admin, and the source path is in the robocopy line below, C:\shortcut. I appreciate the feedback, I apologize for not cleaning up the code better initially.